# How to access GitHub Secrets in Flutter Code

Tags: flutter, dart, github, environment-variables, api-key

I am requesting an **API** from *newsapi.org*

```dart
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=${API_KEY}"));
```

which requires an API key to access the contents so I store the API key in **GitHub** secrets, and now I want to know that how can I access this **API_KEY** stored in GitHub repository secrets to make a **get** request also is there any alternative way to achieve this without exposing the API_KEY?

Comment: Refer: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv